# Accessing SVG use element child/linked nodes via javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

**What i want**

I need to manipulate use elements content dynamically. You know - changing it's sub-tree attributes/structure or attach event handlers and all that stuff. Accessing it's defs reference is not the same as it would only tell me the something about prototype structure and does nothing with real use content instance attached to shadowRoot.

**Problem**

Somehow it couldn't be done in modern browsers (expect ie) or i just missed something.

**What i tried**

After reading the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGUseElement) i tried to use SVGUseElement.instanceRoot, [SVGElementInstance.correspondingUseElement](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#__svg__SVGElementInstance__correspondingUseElement) and even shadowRoot but all that SVG spec properties is missed from SVGUseElement instance in modern browsers (expect ie11) and shadowRoot is always null (chrome inspector shows shadowRoot tree correctly).

**Example**

Here is the example code that correctly works in ie, and seems to be [working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412143/manipulating-objects-with-js) in other browsers old versions:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/weREWJ

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="300">
    <defs>
        <circle id="c1" cx="50" cy="50" r="30" fill="green"/>
    </defs>
    <use id="uc1" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#c1"></use>
    <use id="uc2" x="100" y="100" xlink:href="#c1"></use>
</svg>

let useNode = document.getElementById("uc1");
console.log(useNode.instanceRoot); //undefined
console.log(useNode.shadowRoot); //null
console.log(useNode.correspondingUseElement); //undefined
```

correspondingUseElement

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can reliably do this in most browsers now.

Those attributes were originally going to be removed from SVG 2 due to lack of support in browsers.  However some of them, at least, may be [making a comeback eventually in SVG 2](https://svgwg.org/svg2-draft/single-page.html#struct-InterfaceSVGUseElement) due to the decision to make the `<use>` element use the Shadow DOM as in HTML.

Comment: According to [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412143/manipulating-objects-with-js) this manipulations was possible though instanceRoot property in old browser versions (at least for ie, opera and chrome). I don't believe that nowdays it is impossible and there is no backward compatibility or some new other ways based on shadow dom.

Comment: Chrome [removed this feature in 2014 for security reasons](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=313438&can=1&q=instanceRoot%20SVG&sort=-modified&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). 
  Since Opera now uses the same engine (since 2013) it lost it also.  There is no workaround solution as far as I am aware.